# For Kubernetes high-availability on GCE, does the master load balancer need health checks?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, high-availability

I was following [this blog post on high availability kubernetes](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2017/02/highly-available-kubernetes-clusters.html), but I noticed that when I shut down one of the masters, `kubectl get pods` would intermittently return

```
The connection to the server 1.2.3.4 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

My guess is that this is because the kubernetes-master load balancer does not health check the master instances so the unhealthy master is still in the load balancer rotation.

I just wanted to check and see if this is a known issue or if there something wrong with my setup. I can add the health check manually, but it feels like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It could also be that it is the ALPHA feature status of this.

Comment: Checking the related [design document](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/ha_master.md) it seems that it is accepted at the moment that changes related to the apiserver load balancer take some time to propagte.

But I think this question is offtopic for Stackoverflow and should be placed within the Kubernetes issues on Github.